# Can anyone help me understand the output of this code?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class Example {

    public  static void main(String[] args) {

        byte b = 10;
        short s = 100;
        int x = 125;
        long l = 15000;
        float f = 1.5f;
        double d = 21.231;
        char c = 'c';
        boolean bool = 10>9;

        System.out.println(b+s+x+f+d+c+""+bool);  
    }
}
```

I was expecting `2351.521.231ctrue`. But the output is `356.731true`.

Comment: In Java the `+` arithmetic operator is used for addition and also string concatenation. This operator is also used as a "unary operator" (indicating a positive value).

Comment: Erm ... it is the `+` operator not the "arithmetic" `+` operator.  That's the point.  String concatenation is not arithmetic.   In this example, `+` is both arithmetic and string concatenation at different points in the expression; e.g. `d + c` is arithmetic, but `c+""` is string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` associates to the left and is only treated as string concatenation when one of its (binary) operands is a string, so your operation is

```
System.out.println(((((((b+s)+x)+f)+d)+c)+"")+bool);
```

where all of the numerical `+`'s simply add numbers together (widening where necessary), and only when we actually get to the `+""` do we perform string concatenation.

Comment: Also `'c'` is ASCII 99 so 10+100+125+1.5+21.231+99 = 356.731

Comment: Java converts `byte`, `short` and `char` to `int` on any calculation where the other side doesn't have the same type. So I'm not agreeing with "widening where necessary".

Comment: It is difficult to describe how / when primitive widening occurs in a way that is both concise, accurate and easy to understand.